# Best way to print HTML page that contains embed PDF

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have an application where im printing some information in a modal, and formatting the information with HTML.

At the bottom of the HTML page, I have an Embed pdf.
the idea of that info is that the user needs to print it, so they print the page.

Before I have the PDF embedded I was just printing the HTML code.
Now I'm facing a problem.

When i press print on the page, the HTML code is ok on the print preview, but the  Embedded PDF doesn't appear.

What will be the best option to accomplish that?

I was thinking to convert the PDF to HTML code, but if the user uploads a PDF that is an image that wouldn't work.

Any suggestion!!
Thanks

this is an example of one of the forms.
if you see i will add some HTML code and down below the PDF embedded.
[image]

Comment: There's no easy way of doing this. You'd have to either create a new PDF with the HTML stuff included and print that, or expand the size of your embedded PDF to be large enough (which would likely screw up the pagination). Also, this question is awfully broad; please narrow it to a specific question.

Comment: Thank you @MikeMcCaughan, i haven't been able to find an easy way to do it.
I will probably convert the PDF into an image and give it a try.